# How to create an entry form for excel in my WordPress website?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I would like to create a data entry form for excel in my WordPress website so that all of the staff from different branches can input their information in the form and the director from the head office can view them using the website.

Comment: Do you want to import the entries from the excel file?

Comment: @Jainil,That i have tried and tested but i would like to create an input entry form for the staff of different branches in my WordPress site. That way they would be able to do what they are currently doing in excel.

Comment: You can use contact form 7 to create the form and use Advanced Contact form 7 DB to store data.

Comment: @Jainil, I was just playing with the Contact Form 7 plugin. It looks to be appropriate for a contact form but can it also be transformed into a data entry form? like how you'd insert data in an excel file.

Comment: Yes, you can use Contact Form 7 for that. But it doesn't store the data in database. So you need to use other plugin like Advanced Contact form 7 DB.

Comment: @Jainil,Do you happen to know any helpful web links to make excel type entry forms?